# Swift Error on photofromLibrary

Tags: swift, ios8

I have these two functions connected to two BarButtonItem

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
@IBOutlet weak var libraryTool: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var photoTool: UIBarButtonItem!

 @IBAction func photofromLibrary(sender:AnyObject!){

    let src = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
    let ok = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(src)
    let picker = UIImagePickerController() // see comments below for reason
    picker.sourceType = src
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = false 
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    if let pop = picker.popoverPresentationController {
        let v = sender as UIView
        pop.sourceView = v
        pop.sourceRect = v.bounds
    }
   }


func noCamera(){
    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "No Camera", message: "Sorry, this device has no camera", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style:.Default, handler: nil)
    alertVC.addAction(okAction)
    presentViewController(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If I associate the IBAction photofromLibrary to a button on the UIView all goes well but if I associate a photoTool obviously I get an error on

```
let v = sender as UIView
```

How to set the popover on photoTool ?

Comment: You need to think about the order that your code will be executed in. The error is complaining that you haven't set the `popoverPresentationController`'s barButtonItem before presentation, and you're setting it after presentation.

Comment: What else should I enter?

Comment: i'm tryed and tried ,search and search but i not solve ...how can I do (maybe is a simple thing but I can not find the solution) ?

Comment: Here is some working code to play with: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch17p697pickaMovieOrPhoto/ch30p960pickaMovie/ViewController.swift

Comment: i have edit my code and my question but i don't have a popover on photoTool